# Can't post complex object through Json to Web API - HTTP Error 500

Tags: json, database, api, http, web

I'm using a REST client that I have already used to post other complex objects in my database.

I can't post too much code because it is work-related but here is what I am trying to send to the web API from my rest client:

```
{"BinID":"PBN0012","BinType":"Wash","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-07-11T17:51:49.670028+00:00","ModifiedByUID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[]}
```

That is the object after serialized by JsonConvert.

I'm using HttpWebResponse (and getting an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error - and System.ArgumentException on Xamarin "Illegal Characters in Path".

Even when I try to post directly through SOAP UI I get this message:

```
{
   "$id": "1",
   "Message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

This is what I get when I type "(IP Address....)/Api/Bins/GetBins into my browser:

```
[{"$id":"1","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[{"$id":"2","Bin":{"$ref":"1"},"BinID":"PBN0001","EntrySequence":1}],"BinID":"PBN0001","BinType":"Wash","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"3","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[{"$id":"4","Bin":{"$ref":"3"},"BinID":"PBN0002","EntrySequence":2}],"BinID":"PBN0002","BinType":"Wash","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"5","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[{"$id":"6","Bin":{"$ref":"5"},"BinID":"PBN0003","EntrySequence":3}],"BinID":"PBN0003","BinType":"Wash","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"7","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[{"$id":"8","Bin":{"$ref":"7"},"BinID":"PBN0004","EntrySequence":4}],"BinID":"PBN0004","BinType":"Wash","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"9","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[],"BinID":"PBN0005","BinType":"Wash","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"10","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[],"BinID":"PBN0006","BinType":"Dryer","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"11","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[],"BinID":"PBN0007","BinType":"Dryer","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"12","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[],"BinID":"PBN0008","BinType":"Dryer","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"13","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[],"BinID":"PBN0009","BinType":"Dryer","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"14","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[],"BinID":"PBN0010","BinType":"Dryer","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-06-02T00:00:00","ModifiedByUID":"b6c1b64f-874b-4180-949a-97c77cc4194c"},{"$id":"15","BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[],"BinID":"PBN0011","BinType":"Wash","IsDeleted":false,"ModifiedDateTime":"2014-07-03T15:34:11.67","ModifiedByUID":"9f05ab31-2521-4a7e-9258-b7092aae5058"}]
```

The Bin class consists of:

```
public partial class Bin
{
    public Bin()
    {
        this.BatchBins = new HashSet<BatchBin>();
        this.BinsInUses = new HashSet<BinsInUse>();
    }

    public string BinID { get; set; }
    public string BinType { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ModifiedByUID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BatchBin> BatchBins { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BinsInUse> BinsInUses { get; set; }
}
```

And the table for "Bin" in the database has the following columns:

```
BinID (PK, nvarchar(100),not null)
BinType (nvarchar(5), not null)
IsDeleted (bit, not null)
ModifiedDateTime (datetime,not null)
ModifiedByUID (uniqueidentifier, not null)
```

I know I used the correct types for each of these considering my other objects passed through just fine. Any Suggestions on how to get the json string to post??

Comment: Also I have tried deleting the "+00:00" or the ".670028+00:00" from the time, and I have tried moving " "BatchBins":[],"BinsInUses":[] " to the front of the string but none of that makes any difference.

Comment: And I have tried adding to "BinsInUses" and "BatchBins" before posting but it still doesn't work (And doing something like that which isn't part of the original DB object messed me up when posting another type of object in this database anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so everybody knows, in case they get this kind of error and can't find a solution, you might have the same problem I had.

I'd copied and pasted methods in my API to save time (because many methods/classes had similar names) and I ended up with two methods with the same exact name; I had forgotten to change the method name. Just for future reference.